# MySQL Join two tables with comma separated values

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin, syntax, group-concatenation

I've got two tables as below:

CARLINE

| option_value | option_name |
| --- | --- |
| tipologia_auto_1 | Citycar |
| tipologia_auto_2 | Berlina |
| tipologia_auto_3 | SUV |
| Hobby_1 | football |
| Hobby_2 | Basket |

Datimarketing (is the result of group concat of previous columns)

| Hobby | Car Type | Datimarketing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hobby_1 | tipologia_auto_2, tipologia_auto_3 | Hobby_1, tipologia_auto_2, tipologia_auto_3 |

I am looking to query my Carline table and associate the 'option_name' column with values from the Datimarketing table.

The output should be:

| Hobby | Car Type | Datimarketing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| footbal | Berlina, SUV | football, Berlina, SUV |

Can this be accomplished by CONCAT or FIND_IN_SET?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post ddl (CREATE table...) and sql (insert...)

Comment: Why you need that?

Comment: It is easier to try to answer your question if you provide that

Comment: For small tables, yes.  For big tables, performance will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c0.option_name) Hobby,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c1.option_name) CarType,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c2.option_name) Datimarketing
FROM Datimarketing d
JOIN carline c0 ON FIND_IN_SET(c0.option_value, d.Hobby)
JOIN carline c1 ON FIND_IN_SET(c1.option_value, d.CarType)
JOIN carline c2 ON FIND_IN_SET(c2.option_value, d.Datimarketing)
GROUP BY d.Hobby, d.CarType, d.Datimarketing;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b129417478cbbb6377f21af7f54550b4)

Pay attention - there is no space char after commas. If they are present then trim them in joining conditions by according REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: I, Thank for the answer! I tried to use this procedure for a different kind of database, but when I try to execute the query I always get a Syntax error. The code is the following:

Comment: @FrancescoMarcucci Fiddle demonstrates that the code is correct for provided source data. Apply the technique more accurate.

Comment: As you can see below, I've posted the query that I've built in MySQL database

Comment: @FrancescoMarcucci Do not post an answer - update your question text. And you must understand that I cannot debug on YOUR data. Try step-by-step. Firstly query from `c0` only. Correct? add `c1`. Incorrect? search for error and fix.

Comment: it finally works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've got another question... How could I store these results obtained from the previous query into a new column from the origin table? I've tried with different command, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct. If you have further questions, you can ask them and point back to this one if it's relevant!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c0.option_name)segmento_auto_richiesto,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c1.option_name)alimentazione,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c2.option_name)km_annui_percorsi,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c3.option_name)modalit_di_acquisto,    
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c4.option_name)budget_di_spesa,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c5.option_name)rata_mensile,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c6.option_name)abitudini_di_acquisto,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c7.option_name)giorno_preferito_per_il_ricontatto,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c8.option_name)orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c9.option_name)datimarketing,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c10.option_name)privacy_mkt_all,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c11.option_name)numero_di_componenti_del_nucleo_familiare,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c12.option_name)hobby,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c13.option_name)professione,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c14.option_name)iscritto_ad_associazioni_di_categoria, 
FROM 1459630_form_1 d
JOIN 1459630_field_options c0 ON FIND_IN_SET(c0.option_value, d.segmento_auto_richiesto)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c1 ON FIND_IN_SET(c1.option_value, d.alimentazione)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c2 ON FIND_IN_SET(c2.option_value, d.km_annui_percorsi)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c3 ON FIND_IN_SET(c3.option_value, d.modalit_di_acquisto)    
JOIN 1459630_field_options c4 ON FIND_IN_SET(c4.option_value, d.budget_di_spesa)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c5 ON FIND_IN_SET(c5.option_value, d.rata_mensile)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c6 ON FIND_IN_SET(c6.option_value, d.abitudini_di_acquisto)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c7 ON FIND_IN_SET(c7.option_value, d.giorno_preferito_per_il_ricontatto)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c8 ON FIND_IN_SET(c8.option_value, d.orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c9 ON FIND_IN_SET(c9.option_value, d.datimarketing)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c10 ON FIND_IN_SET(c10.option_value, d.privacy_mkt_all)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c11 ON FIND_IN_SET(c11.option_value, d.numero_di_componenti_del_nucleo_familiare)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c12 ON FIND_IN_SET(c12.option_value, d.hobby)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c13 ON FIND_IN_SET(c13.option_value, d.professione)
JOIN 1459630_field_options c14 ON FIND_IN_SET(c14.option_value, d.iscritto_ad_associazioni_di_categoria)    

GROUP BY d.segmento_auto_richiesto, d.alimentazione, d.km_annui_percorsi, d.modalit_di_acquisto, d.budget_di_spesa, d.rata_mensile, d.abitudini_di_acquisto, d.giorno_preferito_per_il_ricontatto, d.orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto, d.datimarketing, d.privacy_mkt_all, d.numero_di_componenti_del_nucleo_familiare, d.hobby, d.professione,d.iscritto_ad_associazioni_di_categoria;
```